# Python - Where can I ask for help or guidance without losing reputation

Tags: python-3.x

As per topic, are there any newbie friendly mentoring groups perhaps, where I can ask a specific code related question and get an answer specific to my code even if it is a duplicate? I would welcome any suggestions please.(I'm sorry, I have a Dyslexia and Asperger's Syndrome, I easily get confused when reading, therefore need some explicit explanation).

Comment: Hi @B.Malysz, I remember you asked a question yesterday about initialising classes that got marked as a duplicate. Are you still working on that question? You can always comment to users on questions and continue the conversation in more freely and open chat with explanation at http://chat.stackoverflow.com, but I think you need 50 points reputation to participate in chat. You've accepted the answer below, so hopefully you find a helpful source. Don't give up, keep asking! :) Best wishes to you mate!

Comment: (Also, not to discredit this site, but there are many, many other sites that are less restrictive if you need more supervised guidance or one-on-one tutoring, etc.) If you would like suggestions, let us know and I'll gladly suggest some sites that have helped me a lot.

Comment: @downshift thank you for your help now and yesterday. It's not that I gave up, I spent good 3-4 hours reading, tinkering, adjusting, testing. I cannot get the concept, abstractions do not work for me (issue with flexibility of thought). I would greatly appreciate, if you could introduce me to those resources.

Comment: Of course! we all learn differently, and we all try to help each other learn. If you are a more of a visual learner, there should be some good tutorials on youtube. If you want specialized one-on-one tutoring with a professional there are sites that you can video conference with a teacher, only catch is it is not free, usually you must pay for specialized teaching. Lastly, if you are comfortable with "chat" style help IRC channels may work for you (they have helped me tremendously!!) http://freenode.net/ is one really good one. I can suggest more if you want, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code Review community is good for specific questions about your code. The site is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) in case you don't know how to find it. Since the community is about reviewing specific code you will probably get your question answered even if someone has posted code that does the same thing before.